# Side-by-Side Grobs Not Working with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, grob

I would like to create a Shiny document which shows two grobs alongside one another and would like the text inside each grob to be the selected value of a sliderInput.

I am able to easily output two grobs side-by-side in a non-reactive context (first example below) but obviously cannot extract the slider value. However, when I try to output them inside a `renderPlot` reactive context, I am able to extract the slider value, but only the second grob shows up and the connection arrow is not visible.

Can anyone offer a solution that shows both grobs and the reactive value?

````
---
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document
---

```{r global-options, include = FALSE}
## set global options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F, error = F, warning = F, message = F)
```

```{r echo = F, error = F, warning = F, message = F}
## libraries
library(shiny)
library(Gmisc)
library(grid)
library(knitr)

## slider input
sliderInput("nSelect", "Select N:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
```

```{r fig.width = 10, fig.height = 1}
## output grobs normally, but no way to use reactive slider values
g1 <- boxGrob(5,
        x = 0.3,
        y = 0.5)
g2 <- boxGrob(5,
        x = 0.8,
        y = 0.5)
g1
g2
connectGrob(g1, g2, type = "horizontal")
```

```{r fig.width = 10, fig.height = 1}
## output grobs using render plot (allows inputs)
renderPlot({
g3 <- boxGrob(input$nSelect,
        x = 0.3,
        y = 0.5)
g4 <- boxGrob(input$nSelect,
        x = 0.8,
        y = 0.5)
connectGrob(g3, g4, type = "horizontal")
g3
g4
})
```
````

[image]

Comment: Your `renderPlot` renders `g4` since this is the last statement of its body. Close it after you write `connectGrob(g3, g4, type = "horizontal")` (i.e. delete the lines `g3` and `g4`).

Comment: Thanks Stephane - I tried that but doing so only renders the connector arrow - the boxes on either side of it don't render, at least not on my machine/r setup

Comment: @-DJC: Ah sorry, I never used `connectGrob` and I thought it rendered the two connected boxes with the arrow. Isn't there a way to group `g3`, `g4` and the connector in a single object? I'm not familiar with `grid`, I don't know.

Comment: Not to my knowledge - I tried arranging them using various grid arrangements, but my understanding is that the placement of the connector line is contingent on both grobs being placed on a page as it uses those coordinates to place the line. Might end up using DiagrammeR, which is also a great package, to create my actual flowcharts although much prefer the way the nodes/edges look with grob setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `renderPlot` you need to explicitly call `print()`, i.e. all you need to do is:

```
renderPlot({
  g3 <- boxGrob(input$nSelect,
                x = 0.3,
                y = 0.5)
  g4 <- boxGrob(input$nSelect,
                x = 0.8,
                y = 0.5)
  print(connectGrob(g3, g4, type = "horizontal"))
  print(g3)
  print(g4)
})
```

This is an R-feature where anything within an expression won't print unless it is the last element, i.e. you can omit the `print()` for g4 as it will be printed just by being the last.